# Check if form is blank function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I have the following form that takes in standard users information. What I am trying to attempt, which I do not see why it is not working, is to check if all the fields in the form are empty.

Here are the following scripts I am using:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

To achieve this, I thought it would be best to check each field whether or not the field has not selected like so:

```
function checkForm() {              
            if (document.myform.name.value=="") {
             document.getElementById("modal-title").innerHTML = "<h4></h4>";
                document.getElementById("modal-body").innerHTML = "<p>You have left the input box empty." + "<br /><br />" + "Enter a Authorization Number.</p>";
                $("#invalidModal").modal();
                document.getElementById("myform").focus();
                return false
            } 

            if (document.PDF.email.value=="") {
              document.getElementById("modal-title").innerHTML = "<h4></h4>";
                document.getElementById("modal-body").innerHTML = "<p>You have left the input box empty." + "<br /><br />" + "Enter a Authorization Number.</p>";
                $("#invalidModal").modal();
                document.getElementById("myform").focus();
                return false
            }   
        }
```

However, when I try to run it, the modal does not appear.

Here is the modal:

```
<!--- Invalid Entries Modals --->
        <div class="modal fade" id="invalidModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:#428bca !important">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 id="modal-title" class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" style="text-align:center; color:white !important"></h4>
              </div>
              <div id="modal-body" class="modal-body" style="text-align:center;">
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!------------------------------------------>
```

And the following is the form. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated:

```
<form class="form-style-5" id="myform" name="email">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend><span class="number">1</span>Info</legend>
                        <input type="text" name="Name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name *">
                        <input type="email" name="Email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email *"> 
                        <label for="job">Interested in:</label>
                        <select id="DropList" name="products">
                            <optgroup label="Curl Products">
                              <option value="disabled"></option>
                              <option value="curls1">Product1</option>
                              <option value="curls2">Product2</option>
                              <option value="curls3">Product3</option>
                              <option value="curls4">Product4</option>
                              <option value="curls5">Product5</option>
                              <option value="curls6">Product6</option>
                              <option value="other">Other</option>
                            </optgroup>
                            <!--<optgroup label="Outdoors">
                              <option value="football">Football</option>
                              <option value="swimming">Swimming</option>
                              <option value="fishing">Fishing</option>
                              <option value="climbing">Climbing</option>
                              <option value="cycling">Cycling</option>
                              <option value="other_outdoor">Other</option>
                            </optgroup>-->
                        </select>      
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend><span class="number">2</span> Additional Info</legend>
                    <textarea name="field3" placeholder="About Your Hair"></textarea>
                </fieldset>

                    <input type="submit" onclick="return checkForm(this.form)" value="Submit" />
                    <input type="reset" value="Clear" onclick="return resetForm(this.form);" />
            </form>
```

Comment: You've included jQuery twice, BTW. No big deal, just thought I'd point it out. You're also mixing plain DOM methods with jQuery methods which do the same thing, which leads to confusing code. I suggest picking one way of doing it and sticking with it.

Comment: Also, I don't know if it's the cause, but you're opening a modal, then setting focus on the form which is presumably behind the modal... seems odd.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: Why is that odd? and no it isnt causing it. How would I set up the Modal to appear when the user submits the form when empty? And thank you for letting me know about the JQuery appearing twice. I have removed one

Comment: Well, you want to show a modal, right? The term modal implies that the dialog box appears "above" the other content, and the user cannot interact with the other content until the dialog is dismissed. Setting the focus on the form (the other content) means the user's focus is no longer on the dialog they have to interact with. You could set it up such that the form gets focus *after* the dialog closes, that would make sense.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan okay I will try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('#myModal').modal();` only initializes the modal but does not show it. To open the modal directly use `$('#myModal').modal('show');`

See the Bootstrap [methods section](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/)

---

Furthermore I'd recommend binding the focus to the modal close event like this:

```
$('#invalidModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    document.getElementById("myform").focus();
});
```

Then the form wil be focused after the modal is closed.
So in your specific case, the code would be

```
$('#invalidModal').modal(); // initialize modal
$('#invalidModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    // attach the following code to the modal close event
    document.getElementById("myform").focus();
})    

function checkForm() {
    if (document.myform.name.value == "") {
        document.getElementById("modal-title").innerHTML = "<h4></h4>";
        document.getElementById("modal-body").innerHTML = "<p>You have left the input box empty." + "<br /><br />" + "Enter a Authorization Number.</p>";
        $("#invalidModal").modal('show'); // show modal
        return false
    }

    if (document.PDF.email.value == "") {
        document.getElementById("modal-title").innerHTML = "<h4></h4>";
        document.getElementById("modal-body").innerHTML = "<p>You have left the input box empty." + "<br /><br />" + "Enter a Authorization Number.</p>";
        $("#invalidModal").modal('show'); // show modal
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: @ virhonestum: If I would do your approach, would I implement the if statements that checks if input text field is empty in the form after the focus? I am still new to all this and right. I only wanted to initialize the modal but not show it. I want it to show it if the user entered white spaces or if the form was left blank and the user submits the form. So I thought the approach I did would suffice but it appears to no work

Comment: @RobertoFlores I've added a specific code sample, maybe this will clear up some things.

Comment: @ virhonestum: Thank You. That clarifes